# How to get Service Bus Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, servicebus

I'm creating a powershell script to create a service bus. I found a document online for all the commands, however, when I run those commands, they are not identified as valid commands. 
For example when I run New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace, I get an error and when I do a 
Get-Command -Name '*servicebus*', I only get the below options

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                                                                                                             
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                                                                                                             
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusQueueJob             0.11.1     AzureRM.Scheduler                                                                                                                                                                  
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusTopicJob             0.11.1     AzureRM.Scheduler                                                                                                                                                                  
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusQueueJob             0.11.1     AzureRM.Scheduler                                                                                                                                                                  
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusTopicJob             0.11.1     AzureRM.Scheduler
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need use `*servicebus*`. * matches 0 to multiple characters.

Just use following cmdlet.

```
PS C:\Users\v-shshui> Get-Command -Name "*servicebus*"

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace                     0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceAuthorizationRule    0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey                  0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueue                         0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueueAuthorizationRule        0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueueKey                      0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription                  0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusTopic                         0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusTopicAuthorizationRule        0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmServiceBusTopicKey                      0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusQueueJob             0.12.0     AzureRM.Scheduler
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusTopicJob             0.12.0     AzureRM.Scheduler
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace                     0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceAuthorizationRule    0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey                  0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusQueue                         0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusQueueAuthorizationRule        0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusQueueKey                      0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription                  0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusTopic                         0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusTopicAuthorizationRule        0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmServiceBusTopicKey                      0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace                  0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceAuthorizationRule 0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmServiceBusQueue                      0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmServiceBusQueueAuthorizationRule     0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription               0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmServiceBusTopic                      0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmServiceBusTopicAuthorizationRule     0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusQueueJob             0.12.0     AzureRM.Scheduler
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmSchedulerServiceBusTopicJob             0.12.0     AzureRM.Scheduler
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace                     0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceAuthorizationRule    0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmServiceBusQueue                         0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmServiceBusQueueAuthorizationRule        0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription                  0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmServiceBusTopic                         0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmServiceBusTopicAuthorizationRule        0.1.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus
```

Also, you could check your Azure PowerShell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

For now, the latest version is 3.7.0. If your are old version, you could try to install the latest version from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.7.0-March2017).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an older version of Azure PowerShell installed which doesn't include the `AzureRm.ServiceBus` module. Simply install the latest version of [Azure PowerShell](http://aka.ms/webpi-azps) using [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to get the Service Bus cmdlets you are looking for.